# Class inheritance, how to improve?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

i have a little question that is discouraging me i have this portion of code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "Hello World!!!"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
        self.inherited = self.A.variable
```

the thing is that i have a bunch of variables on class A that i don't want to instantiate and declare on class B one by one
is there a way to improve the code?

Comment: You are mixing/confusing composition and inheritance.

Comment: also, what's that `Object` with uppercase O?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Most likely he meant [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a mix of composition and inheritance. It seems like you want to exclusively use composition:

```
class A(Object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.c = C()
         self.e = E()

class B(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C()
        self.d = D()
```

Where `C`, `D`, and `E` are components that group variables and methods together. Now A and B only share the component of C. You should look for more complete composition tutorials

Edit: Actually just double checking it looks like your just confused about instantiating super class variables. Other answers correctly addressed this with `super`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding two concepts.

For example, you are trying to do both composition *and* inheritance.

```
class A(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "Hello World!!!"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
        self.inherited = self.A.variable
```

When you do this, you are saying, "Make B also an A object." In other words, the following works:

```
class A(object): # can omit this (object) in python3
  def __init__(self):
    self.value_from_a = 'Im from A!'

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value_from_b = 'im a bbbbb!'


b = B()
print(b.value_from_a)
print(b.value_from_b)
```

So, in your case the way to do this is to not try to make an A both the base as well as part of B.

Note if you are using Python2 the above syntax will be slightly different.